# How to install django spirit ? I am getting the error command not found: spirit

Tags: python, django, pip

I tried install django spirit using

```
mkvirtualenv env -p /usr/bin/python3
pip install django-spirit
spirit startproject mysite
```

but get the error:

> spirit command not found

Any solutions ?

Comment: did installation of the django-spirit passed without errors?

Comment: "pip install django-spirit" went well in both python 2.7 and 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default from pip you installed the `spirit==0.4.8` version, but command `spirit` is added in new 0.5 version, so you should install from git repo:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nitely/Spirit.git
```

Comment: I still get the same error after installing spirit 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

@Vardha Try the following steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/nitely/Spirit.git
2. python3 -m venv spirit-env  ## Create the Virtual Environment
3. source spirit-env/bin/activate ## Activate the Virtual
4. pip install `<path_to_cloned_spirit>`/Spirit
5. cd `<path_to_cloned_spirit>`/Spirit
6. spirit startproject forum
7. cd forum
8. python manage.py migrate
9. python manage.py runserver